# iPad input without any input fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'd like to write a simple "C is for Cat" program for the iPad.  The user presses the C virtual key and a cat shows up and meows.

Q: Using jQuery and/or jQuery mobile, how can I have the keyboard appear without there being any input controls on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of all of the browser hooks present in iPad's Safari, but I really don't think there's a way to trigger this without first focusing on an input field of some sort.

Perhaps you could create a hidden text input field and then give it focus upon page load? Then when they type characters, you could listen for the onChange event and react appropriately.

Other than that, I don't think there's a way to capture key presses.

Answer (score 1):

Cool. Try this:

```
$("<input type='text' style='opacity: 0.01'/>").appendTo("body").focus();
```

Hmm...only other thing I can suggest is to make a giant invisible `<textarea />`...? Then get the user to tap it.

Comment: Thanks NeXXeuS!  This technique shows creativity, but the iPad doesn't like the .focus() event.

Comment: Hmm...only other thing I can suggest is to make a giant invisible `<textarea />`...? Then get the user to tap it.

Comment: Yeah, I think maybe some sort of a 'tap here to activate' maybe.  Good idea.